# can't find image child node jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't find the child node alt attribute and I know I have the right parent. What am I doing wrong?

Bar1 is good but I just can't find bar2.

```css
<ul class="small-image">
  <li><a id="foo1"><img src="../images/imageSlide/s2.jpg" alt="pic1"></a></li>
  <li><a id="foo2"><img src="../images/imageSlide/s2.jpg" alt="pic2"></a></li>
<ul>
```

```js
$('ul.small-image li a').bind('click',function(){
    var elm = '#'+$(this+'div:first-child').attr('alt');
    //var elm = '#'+$(this+'img').attr('alt');
    console.log("Bar1: "+$(this).attr('id')) ;
    console.log("Bar2: "+elm);

});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to select `div:first-child` when there's no div?

Comment: This is invalid: '#'+$(this+'div:first-child').attr('alt'); What is Bar 2 anyway? What are you trying to get? The alt attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to select the alt from the image

```
$('ul.small-image li a').bind('click',function(){
    console.log("Bar1: "+ $(this).attr('id')) ;
    console.log("Bar2: "+ $(this).find("img").attr("alt")); // Find the image INSIDE the current A

});​
```

`this` will be the A, so you have to find the image inside the clicked a and get the attribute `alt`. Just use `$(this).find("img").attr("alt")`

And a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kL5P5/

Answer (score 0):

The child node attribute only returns the first child (foo1 only). I think you might want to check out jQuery's [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function.